# Select and group by string occurrences using LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

I have some data that I would like to count and group by. It looks like this:

Cat Cat Dog Dog Dog

My goal is to get a list of objects that have the name of the animal and the number of times it appears in the data set

**Object 1**

Name: Cat

NumberAppearances: 2

**Object 2**

Name: Dog

NumberAppearances: 3

I am trying to do this with a LINQ query and this is what I have but the count is wrong. I think it's counting the length instead of the number of times it appears. How would I modify this?

```
animalData.Select(x => x.AnimalType).Distinct().ToList().ForEach(a => 

    AnimalObject animal = new AnimalObject();

    animal.Name = a.Name;

    animal.Number = a.Distinct().Count();

    animalList.Add(animal);

});
```

Comment: Try `animalData.Select(x => x.AnimalType).GroupBy(...)`. When you're going to use LINQ first do some exercises with all `Enumerable` extension methods to get them into your system.

Comment: Can you explain why you've inserted a bunch of "distinct" clauses? The point of a distinct clause is to *remove duplicates* which then makes it impossible to *count the number of duplicates*.  I am interested to learn why people make mistakes when programming; what led you to believe that removing the duplicates would be a good way to count the duplicates?

Comment: What is the type of `AnimalType`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is all you need to accomplish your task:

```
var result = animalData.GroupBy(x => x.AnimalType).Select(g => new AnimalObject 
             {
                 Name = g.Key,
                 Number = g.Count()
             }).ToList();

foreach (var e in result)
    Console.WriteLine($"Name: {e.Name} \n NumberAppearances: {e.Number}");
```

*note* -

1. as your LINQ query is currently written, you need not call *distinct* nor *ToList* as the former will result
   in the incorrect outcome and the latter is unnecessary.
2. stick to good naming conventions, you don't need the *Object* suffix after the type name so just *Animal* will suffice.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this one without creating a new object, with the help of Dictionary:

```
var animalCounts = animalList.GroupBy(a => a.AnimalType).ToDictionary(
                                 grp => grp.Key, grp => grp.ToList().Count());
foreach(var animalCount in animalCounts) {
   Console.WriteLine($"Name: {animalCount.Key}{Environment.NewLine}NumberOfApperances: {animalCount.Value}");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Group the data by AnimalType, then transform it to AnimalObject.

```
var result = animalData.GroupBy(x => x.AnimalType)
                            .Select(g => new AnimalObject { Name = g.Key, Number = g.Count() })
                            .ToList();
```